# Webpack Not Loading Images?

Tags: webpack

I'm new to Webpack and my images are getting a 404 error in console. I've spent hours researching here and believe I've followed all the steps.

Here's my Webpack config:

```
      module: {

       rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
},
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
      },
```

I've imported my image like so `import tickets from './views/img/tickets.png'`

After some research I put require in the HTML. `<img class="tickets" src= require("./img/tickets.png") alt="tickets" />`

So I'm not sure what's happening. My images are appearing in the Dist folder too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just figured it out and wanted to share in case it helps someone else. After importing, I wrote:

var ticketsPic = document.getElementById('tickets');
ticketsPic.src = tickets;

Article for ref: https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/handling-images-e1a2a2c28f8d